# db->insert_id() Always Equals Zero

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an AJAX function in my controller:

```
public function add_display_row($shape, $rows) {
        $newRecord = array(
            'work_id' => '',
            'section_id' => (int)$rows + 1,
            'shape' => $shape
        );

        //insert new record after last
        $newro = array();
        for( $c=1; $c<6; $c++){
            $newRecord['ordinal'] = $c;
            $newRecord['size_id'] = $this->work_model->get_size_from_specs($shape, $c);
            $insNew = $this->work_model->save_new_featured_shape($newRecord);
            $newRecord['item_id'] = $insNew;
            array_push($newro, $newRecord);
        }

        print_r($newro);
    }
```

And in the model

```
public function save_new_featured_shape($record) {
      $this->db->trans_begin();
      $this->db->insert('work_featured', $record);

      if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        return false;
      } else {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $insert_id;
      }
    }
```

After all 5 records are inserted, I am returning the array to the caller and the item_id (which should be the insert id of each) equals 0.

I need the insert_id to be returned to build up the DOM element I will then insert into the DOM.

Can anyone see why it is zero?

Comment: Have your data insert into database???

Comment: data is inserted into the database correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify add_display_row as following.

```
   public function add_display_row($shape, $rows) {
    //$this->load->model('work_model');
    $newRecord = array(
        'work_id' => '',
        'section_id' => (int)$rows + 1,
        'shape' => $shape
    );
    $new_arr=array();
    //insert new record after last
    $newro = array();
    for( $c=1; $c<6; $c++){
        $newRecord['ordinal'] = $c;
        $newRecord['size_id'] =  $this->work_model->get_size_from_specs($shape, $c);
        $insNew = $this->save_new_featured_shape($newRecord);
        $new_arr['item_id'] = $insNew;
        $new_arr_arr=array_merge($newRecord,$new_arr);
        array_push($newro, $new_arr_arr);
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($newro);
    }
```

and model function as following.

```
  public function save_new_featured_shape($record) {
  $this->db->trans_begin();
  $this->db->insert('work_featured', $record);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
  if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    return false;
  } else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();

    return $insert_id;
  }
}
```